# Is this c++ template code valid? g++ compiles it but clang won't

Tags: c++, templates, clang, libstdc++

I am trying to compile a small c++ program using clang with the default C++ standard library(4.6.2) on Fedora. Clang itself compiles okay and a test program using only  compiles and runs fine.

My other program uses ropes which clang complains about.

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/ext/ropeimpl.h:433:2:
>   error: use of
>         undeclared identifier '_Data_allocate'
>           _Data_allocate(_S_rounded_up_size(__old_len + __len));

A [bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=6454) was filed against clang for this error message and the resolution was clang is correct, the library code is invalid.

> Clang is correct here. There are no type-dependent arguments in the
>   call to
>   _Data_allocate, so name lookup fails at template definition time.

The context for the failing code:

```
  // Concatenate a C string onto a leaf rope by copying the rope data.
  // Used for short ropes.
  template <class _CharT, class _Alloc>
    typename rope<_CharT, _Alloc>::_RopeLeaf*
    rope<_CharT, _Alloc>::
    _S_leaf_concat_char_iter(_RopeLeaf* __r, const _CharT* __iter, size_t __len)
    {
      size_t __old_len = __r->_M_size;
      _CharT* __new_data = (_CharT*)
    _Data_allocate(_S_rounded_up_size(__old_len + __len));
      _RopeLeaf* __result;

      uninitialized_copy_n(__r->_M_data, __old_len, __new_data);
      uninitialized_copy_n(__iter, __len, __new_data + __old_len);
      _S_cond_store_eos(__new_data[__old_len + __len]);
      __try
    {
      __result = _S_new_RopeLeaf(__new_data, __old_len + __len,
                     __r->_M_get_allocator());
    }
      __catch(...)
    {
      _RopeRep::__STL_FREE_STRING(__new_data, __old_len + __len,
                      __r->_M_get_allocator());
      __throw_exception_again;
    }
      return __result;
    }
```

My question is, if this code is not valid, is there an easy workaround? g++ compiles this okay.

Comment: Did you consider making a bug report on http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Digging through the libstdc++ source, it appears that the definition of member function `_Data_allocate` results from an expansion of the `__ROPE_DEFINE_ALLOCS` macro in the definition of template `_Rope_base` (note that template instantiation `rope<_CharT, _Alloc>` publicly extends `_Rope_base<_CharT, _Alloc>`).

You could try qualifying the call to `_Data_allocate` further. Instead of:

```
_Data_allocate(_S_rounded_up_size(__old_len + __len));
```

Try:

```
_Rope_base<_CharT, _Alloc>::_Data_allocate(_S_rounded_up_size(__old_len + __len));
```

Or simply:

```
_Base::_Data_allocate(_S_rounded_up_size(__old_len + __len));
```

because of the protected `typedef _Rope_base<_CharT, _Alloc> _Base;` in the definition of `rope<_CharT, _Alloc>`.

**EDIT:** I don't have Clang installed locally, but I tested this out with the [online Clang 3.0 compiler demo](http://llvm.org/demo/index.cgi).

This highly pared-down version fails to compile with Clang 3.0 (error: use of undeclared identifier '_Data_allocate'):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>

template <typename _CharT, class _Alloc>
class _Rope_base : public _Alloc
{
public:
    typedef typename _Alloc::template rebind<_CharT>::other _DataAlloc;
    static _CharT * _Data_allocate(std::size_t __n) {
        return _DataAlloc().allocate(__n);
    }
};

template <typename _CharT, class _Alloc = std::allocator<_CharT> >
class rope : public _Rope_base<_CharT, _Alloc>
{
protected:
    typedef _Rope_base<_CharT, _Alloc> _Base;

public:
    rope()
    {
        _Data_allocate(0);
    }
};

int main()
{
    rope<char> r;
}
```

By qualifying the call to `_Data_allocate` in either way suggested above, Clang 3.0 succeeds in compiling it.

Comment: +1, Also, if you are to fix the library, you can alternatively qualify the call with `this`: `this->_Data_allocate` becomes a dependent name and that means that the resolution is postponed until parameter substitution and the correct member function in the base template will be found. Another solution would be to add `using _Base::_Data_allocate;` to the `rope` class template, that would bring the base function into scope.

Comment: I tried this-> but clang complained with "error: invalid use of 'this' outside of a nonstatic member function".

Comment: @Daniel: adding `using _Base::_Data_allocate;` worked fine for me (as it should) on the Clang demo page.

Comment: Just for reference, this issue is discussed in Item 43: "Know how to access names in templatized base classes" from the 3rd Edition of Effective C++ by Scott Meyers.

Comment: @Adam12: I have not looked at the library, and assumed that `_Data_allocate` was a member function of `_Base` and that it was being called from another member function. If the member function is static that will not work, if the function where the call is being done is static, then there is no `this` either.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Right. My mistake. I tried adding `using _Base::_Data_allocate;` within the constructor definition. I misread David's note about adding it *to the `rope` template*.